# adding element with ng-click using angular.element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to add a couple of custom buttons to the right part of the header of fullcalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/).

I am using angular.element to add the buttons like this:

```
   var calendarHeaderRight = angular.element(".fc-header-right");
   if (calendarHeaderRight)
       calendarHeaderRight.html('<div><a href="#" ng-click="toggleCalendarList()" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Calendar</a><a href="#" ng-click="toggleCalendarList()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">List </a></div>');
```

The buttons do get appended to the calendar and are displayed. The problem is that nothing is happening when I click the buttons.

So the question is, how do I append elements which can be clicked ?

thanks

Thomas

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: Without compiling, Angular can't bind to any directives.  That binding is where all the Angular-y goodness comes from.  See @Tyler.z.yang's answer for a link.

Answer (score 5):

```
var element = $compile(angular.element('<div><a href="#" ng-click="toggleCalendarList()" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Calendar</a><a href="#" ng-click="toggleCalendarList()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">List </a></div>'))(scope);
```

then you can wrapped this element in your div. [Here is angular document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) about compile.

: ) enjoy it.

Comment: Directive is another way to solve this problem. But that is basic part for angular directive. : )

Answer (score 0):

```
    var html = angular.element('<div><a href="#" ng-click="toggleCalendarList()" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Calendar</a><a href="#" ng-click="toggleCalendarList()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">List </a></div>')
    var compiled = $compile(html)
    calendarHeaderRight.html(html)
    compiled($scope)
```

View compilation in Angular basically traverses the entire DOM tree of whatever node you give it, creating a single function, that when called will execute every linking function from every directive it finds in that DOM tree, with the appropriate scope, element, attributes and (optionally) controllers.

Pretty much the same thing Tyler did just broken down.